# This formula can't be entered because it uses more than 64 levels of nesting

Tags: excel, if-statement

If i get this message of 64 levels, am i able somehow still use more than 64 if? or i need to think new formula?

Maybe someone can help me to create new?

I need to check if one cell equal to other more than 64 cells, and if it is equal i need to get different value.

For example

`=IF(AJ$2=info!$AJ$2;info!$AJ3;IF(Production!AJ$2=info!$AK$2;info!$AK3;IF(Production!AJ$2=info!$AL$2;info!$AL3;IF(Production!AJ$2=info!$AM$2;info!$AM3;IF(AJ$2=info!$AN$2;info!$AN3;IF(Production!AJ$2=info!$AO$2;info!$AO3;IF(AJ$2=info!$AP$2;info!$AP3;....`

i have like this table:

[image]

And im cheking if my other cell equal to number in table and if yes, returning sign "x" or "-". (im doing this checking for a lot of rows.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/819448/how-to-reformulate-excel-formula-with-too-many-levels-of-nesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HLOOKUP:

```
=HLOOKUP(AJ$2;info!$AJ$2:$CC3,2,0)
```

To change the row index as is is dragged down:

```
=HLOOKUP(AJ$2;info!$AJ$2:$CC3,ROW(2:2),0)
```

Comment: oh my... Thank you!! is there any way to drag this formula down to change row index?

Comment: @SkirmanteValentaite see edit, please remember to come back after the question is 15 minutes old and mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Thank you!! :) now i will know that way and i always will use :)